# shell script running in php gives error .sh: Permission denied

Tags: php, linux

I am running a php file through browser which run the shell script but i recive the error ".sh: Permission denied"
My Php File is

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/var/www/html/test.sh 2>&1');
echo "$output";
```

My Shell Script is

```
#! /bin/bash
scp -r -i /home/ec2-user/key.pem /var/www/html/test ec2-user@172.16.11.12:/var/www/html/
echo "hello world"
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Your scp line is not right.  `echo "hello world` seems to be the content of your file.

Comment: echo "Hello World" is part of script, we can also remove this line.

Answer (score 0):

We found that the script, test.sh, would fail with "Permission denied" when executed by php's shell_exec when the script was located in either /var/www/html/ and /root (which was the id commands being executed by shell_exec).  It executed just fine when when we moved the script to /usr/local/bin.  The script also worked when executed manually on a console in all 3 directories.  This also excludes the mount noexec theory. I don't see any restrictions documented in php documentation for shell_exec, or php.ini. Neither AppArmor or SELinux are enabled on the host.  There were no errors in /var/log that mentioned the script.  int_get('open_basedir') and strace of the the php process when running the .php file (you can do that on the command line) would be the only other thing that has come up.  Any other ideas?  I am stumped.

Comment: yes the permission is fine as written above.

Comment: I don't see where you wrote that... can you just grab me `ls -l '/var/www/html/test.sh` from your amazon instance just to be sure?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user   113 Dec 29 07:46 test.sh

My test.php file is at /var/www/html and my test.sh and .pm files are at /home/ec2-user/

Comment: Perfect.  Does it work if you execute the script manually?  Maybe the file system is mounted with noexec.

Comment: yes it is executed perfectally fine through shell.

Comment: You tested that on the server, right?  Can you try comment out the scp line to see if the echo works by itself when you execute the script via php?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226546/discussion-between-allan-wind-and-yasir-iqbal).

Comment: You PHP script is probably executed with the web_user (apache ? www-data ?).

Did you tried to add ec2-user to www-data/apache group ?

Did you tried `chown ec2-user:apache /var/www/html/test.sh` or even `chown apache:apache /var/www/html/test.sh` ?